# Selenium IDE - best way to not repeat actions that are common for all test cases

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

For all my Selenium IDE TCs I have a common step of logging in using username, password and logging out at the end for each TC.

The best way I can think of is

creating the user id, password, base url as variables in a common file. That way I don't have to repeat the steps common for all test cases and if the user ID or base url change - I dont have to modify each and every TC.

Was also looking at robot framework to solve this but could not figure it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you might be better off with Selenium RC or Selenium 2 (WebDriver) which will allow you to have an initialise to setup id, password and setup files? A few examples are shown in this post which I came across earlier: [Selenium Test - preserve session across multiple test runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230197/selenium-test-preserve-session-across-multiple-test-runs)
Sorry if these are things you already knew :)

Answer (score 2):

> creating the user id, password, base url as variables in a common file

You are totally right! Also you can create separate files for actions that will be repeated ("methods") and organize them into different folders. Then compose different test suites with these files (use relative paths like ../../../../). In test suite folder you can store file with variables that concern only this test suite and test suite file itself.
For example, create Authentication folder with Login.html, Logout.html test cases. Test suite will be look something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
  <title>Test Suite</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium"><tbody>
<tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="StoredVariables.html">StoredVariables</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../../../Tests/Authentication/Login.html">Login</a></td></tr>
...
<tr><td><a href="../../../../Tests/SomeActions/SomeActions.html">SomeActions</a></td></tr>
...
<tr><td><a href="../../../../Tests/Authentication/Logout.html">Logout</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Variables will live during all test suite.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I have a file create_new_title.html which has                                    <tr><td><a href="C:/Users/abc/Desktop/selenium TCs/common.html">login</a></td></tr>                              common.html has                                                                 <tr> 
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/ui/login/Logout.ddx</td>                                  but  when i execute create_new_trait.html it gives me an error.

Comment: What kind of error? Run selenium IDE, then write your command `open | /ui/login/Logout.ddx`. Save test case (ctrl+s). Now you can add this test case to any test suite (File > Add test case or ctrl+d) and save test suite (File > Save Test suite). When you will run your tests, click button `Play entire test suite`. You can edit test suite file in e.g. notepad++ and replace absolute paths to relative ones, so you can move your tests' folder in any place and it still will work.

Comment: I want to log in and log out for each test case. So if there is something like a common file which can be used in these test cases instead of having login details inside each test case - if the usre id or password change I have to change it in common file and not all the test cases - thanks

Comment: Yes, I understood you intentions. But lets differ `Test Suite` and `Test Case` terms. *Test Case* - this is your login, logout, ... whatever actions. They are separate files that you created only once and re-use it many times. *Test Suite* - combination of this Test Cases. See screenshots: http://clip2net.com/s/1NBBH, http://clip2net.com/s/1NBFN, http://clip2net.com/s/1NBEs, http://clip2net.com/s/1NBET,

Comment: Thank you. Ended up writing a common class in selenium webdriver.