# How to implement a common login session to execute multiple test cases in Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have removed the login functionality from all the test cases and created a separate login test class to handle it. Now I am working on to just run the login test case once and then somehow implement a session where all the test cases for that particular application gets executed, one by one or in parallel. (As of now I don't mind either to run them sequentially or in parallel).

Could anyone tell me how can this be achieved? Just so you know we cannot use Selenium Grid in our project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  "Please help me" is far too broad a question, and does not lead to answers that are actually useful for you.  Please [edit] your question to be more specific about what help you need.

Comment: Pls refer to this qustion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230197/selenium-test-preserve-session-across-multiple-test-runs/54638918#54638918.